# How to protect software server

Tags: software, hacking

In the our contract with our service provider, how do I protect us from having their server hacked and our personal information compromised?

Comment: You cannot use a contract to secure a server.

Comment: What do you mean by "protect"?

Comment: You need to put in a firewall/encryption, and the network switches are dumb machines, and therefore don't forward information, unless you put a packet sniffer on the line.

Comment: You can have something that says "Thou shall not hack this server." However, that won't stop a determined person from actually hacking the server.

Comment: Maybe some kind of insurance product is what you're looking for. You could find out what your desired level of coverage would cost and use that to negotiate price with your service provider.

Answer (score -1):

In a contract, you can state what a service provider must do (and perhaps anticipate remedies in case of breach). Let's say, hypothetically, that installing the No-Hack™ server absolutely prevents hacking into a system, so you can make it a condition of the contract that they must do that. Then if they fail to do so, they are in breach. If you suffer a loss, then they would have to make you whole by compensating you. You could, for example, also say in the contract that they must pay $100,000 for every "incident" (be sure to define "an incident"). However, there is no way to infallibly guarantee an outcome by tweaking contract language. So the most important thing to do is say what you want them to do (not what result you want to hold).

Comment: "You could, for example, also say in the contract that they must pay $100,000 for every "incident"" - no you can't. This is a penalty clause and unenforceable unless $100,000 was a reasonable pre-estimate of the damage suffered by a data breach and not excessive (which it clearly is)

Comment: I grant that the specific number was a bit out there; I have no idea what The Law defines as being a reasonable estimate of damages for such an breach.

Comment: @DaleM When a penalty clause is unenforceable, wouldn't it be possible to add a liability clause? (the service provider pays for any damages to the client which result from [legalese for "getting pwned"])

Comment: @Philipp but why bother? If the person breaches a contract you have a right to sue for damages